# Tomcat returns 400 without running a servlet

Tags: tomcat7, java-7, servlet-3.0, http-1.0

My device has UBlox (hardware component) to send POST HTTP/1.0 requests.

Headers that I receiving in Tomcat are following:

```
POST sc2-http-connector-3.0.0/report HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Host: xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
Connection: TE, close
TE: trailers
Content-Length: 152
```

Request body is actually binary data. Tomcat just returns 400 to the client and not even running servlet which just prints header, body, and so on.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("getMethod :: " + request.getMethod());
    System.out.println("getContentLength :: " + request.getContentLength());
    System.out.println("getContentType :: " + request.getContentType());
    System.out.println("getProtocol :: " + request.getProtocol());
    System.out.println("getRemoteAddr :: " + request.getRemoteAddr());
    System.out.println("getRemoteHost :: " + request.getRemoteHost());
    System.out.println("getRemotePort :: " + request.getRemotePort());
    System.out.println("getRemoteUser :: " + request.getRemoteUser());

    printHeaders(request);

    printByteStream(request.getInputStream());

    System.out.println("------------- parts, if any -------------");
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        System.out.println("size :: " + part.getSize());
        System.out.println("contentType :: " + part.getContentType());
        System.out.println("name :: " + part.getName());
        printHeaders(part);
        printByteStream(part.getInputStream());
    }

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

Doesn't seem to be a problem with headers. I think it should be something wrong with the data. But still, why Tomcat returns 400 and do not pass control to my servlet? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path in POST command was missing leading slash, simply.